# How to read hundreds of csv files from a directory and sum a specific column from each of them?

Tags: python, csv

I have around 650 csv files in a directory. Each of them have three columns with header(#ch# ##kev## ###count###), and 2050 rows.One of the file image is shown here partly.

```
    ch       kev     count
     0        0        0
     1        0        0
     2        0        0
     .        .        .
     .        .        .  
     .        .        .
    100       0        30
    101       0        70
     .        .        .
     .        .        .
    200       .        1000
    201       0        1037
     .        .        .
     .        .        .
    2050      0        0
```

I would like to sum of column(###count###) for a specific range (100 -200) of value of column(#ch#). I am able to write the program only for a single csv file is show below:

```
    import csv

    cr = csv.reader(open("D:\\Pythontest\\test1.csv", 'r'))
    cr.next()
    ['ch', 'kev', 'count']

    total = 0

    for row in cr:
        if 100 <= int(row[0]) <= 200:
           total += int(row[2])

    print total
```

But I don't know how to write the program for all of the files at a time. I would like to extract sum value from each of the file and put them together in a separate file. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Did you consider using a database?
Also, if you need a total from all files, then a simple batch command can combine all of them into one file (e.g `cat *.csv > all.csv`), which you can then process with your original program.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a working program for one file all you need is a way to use that program on each file. I suggest doing the following:

- Learn how to use the glob module to list all the csv files, http://pymotw.com/2/glob/
- Move your code to a function, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm, taking the filename as an argument and returning the total for that file.
- Loop over each file that glob gives you and run the function, adding up the total as you go.

Good luck and if you run into a problem with one of the steps feel free to post a new question that's more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the list of files from the directory and then do a for loop.

Here is a function:

```
def find_csv_files( path_to_dir, suffix=".csv" ):
filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]
```

Then simply use it and do a for loop:

```
filenames = find_csv_files("dir/directory")
for name in filenames:
  print name
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
import os
import csv

def get_all_files(directory, extension='.csv'):
    dir_list = os.listdir(directory)
    csv_files = []
    for e in dir_list:
        if e.endswith(extension):
            csv_files.append(os.path.realpath(e))
    return csv_files

def sum_from_csv(csv_file):
    cr = csv.reader(open(csv_file, 'r'))
    cr.next()
    ['ch', 'kev', 'count']

    total = 0

    for row in cr:
        if 100 <= int(row[0]) <= 200:
           total += int(row[2])

    print total

csv_files = get_all_files('D:\\Pythontest\\')

for each in csv_files:
    sum_from_csv(each)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to write the script but some errors are shown like:File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>; File"<stdin>", line2, in get_all_files; NameError: global name 'listdir' is not defined. How could I solve this problem, I will be glad to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now another errors are shown: File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>;File "<stdin>" line 2, in sum_from_csv;IOError:[Error 2]No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python27\\test1.csv'  ......actutally my directory is 'D:\\Pythontest\\' and inside all the files are named by test1, test2....I am looking forward to your response. Thank you

Comment: Show me the file list, print `print csv_files` and show output here!

Comment: Now I can run the program. I just delete the part'(os.path.realpath)',  and I already write the results in a different .txt file, where I have sum results in a column from 600 csv files.Now I would like to write the sum results laterally across row for every 20 columns. i.e. sum results of column(1-20) will be in 1st column, sum results of column (21-41) will be placed in 2nd row, ........Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you kinldy let me know how can I do that, I am looking for your response. Thank you